# opengl + glew in Eclipse (for windows)

Tags: eclipse, opengl, glew

I'm trying to get glew to work under eclipse (mingw) in windows. Seems as if it is extremely unusual not to use Visual Studio in this context. The install instructions for glew is simply "use the project file in build/vc6/"...

The glew readme also writes:
"If you wish to build GLEW from scratch (update the extension data from
the net or add your own extension information), you need a Unix
environment (including wget, perl, and GNU make).  The extension data
is regenerated from the top level source directory with:
make extensions"

In order to get glew to work in eclipse and windows I have to compile it in a unix environment? Is there no other way?
Sure, it would probably be a learning experience to pull that off (if I were to succeed) but I feel that my time is best spent actually working on my project. And even if I did manage to crosscompile everything, would it work in anything but Visual Studio?

Is the whole thing unfeasible and the best solution is to install Visual Studio?

Google haven't been of much help, I feel like I am the only one that has ever attempted to do this (is there a good reason this?).

Answer (score 3):

Well if you still require some flexibility that the VS compiler doesn't always hold, you could try downloading the glew source zip file (on their main sourceforge page). Saying you have to have a Unix environment in order for it to work with eclipse is a huge mistake, as I have it working with MinGW at the moment. Just download the source, extract it, and create/put this batch file into the directory with "Makefile":

```
@echo on
set SYSTEM=mingw
set GLEW_DEST=C:\...[where you extracted it to]...\glew-1.7.0\usr
path = %PATH%;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;

make all
make install.all

pause
```

Change `...[where you extracted it to]...` to the path you extracted the downloaded source zip to. Save that and run it, and you should see a "usr" folder containing all the dlls, libs, and headers you'll need. Copy those over to their respective OpenGL counterparts (or just anywhere where you'll be able to specify them in Eclipse later).

Now, in Eclipse, make a new project and at least be sure to include this somewhere:

```
#ifndef GLEW_STATIC
#define GLEW_STATIC
#endif //GLEW_STATIC


#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/wglew.h>
```

If you put the glew headers somewhere besides the OpenGL headers, you may not have to use `GL/`. Now include the libraries by going into `Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->MinGW C++ Linker->Libraries` and add the following libraries:

```
glew32
opengl32
glu32
glew32.dll
```

Add any library search paths you'll need. In my case I just used `"C:\MinGW\lib"` as a second measure.

Now save all your project files, use `Project->Clean...`, and build your project. If you don't get any glew errors and your project is prepared you should be able to run it.

Hope that works! It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Download the Windows 32-bit binary for GLEW here: http://glew.sourceforge.net/index.html
2. Follow the instruction to link your project to GLEW: http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html
3. Make sure your Eclipse is also setup to compile with mingw. (I assume you've done this.)
4. `cout << "Hello world!";`

Comment: As a side comment, I've went through the entire labour of making cygwin to work with Eclipse. Not very pretty. I eventually went back to VS2008 for C++, and Eclipse for Java and Python. Your call.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and got a bunch of linkingproblems. I've spent quite some time with google on resolving this and I can't find anything relevant. Maybe I've just messed something up but I decided that this issue was taking way to much time and I've mentally prepared for installing visual studio and will probably do that later tonight. Thanks again.

Comment: Care to share your error messages? (Or if you've given up by going to VS like I did, all's good. `;]`)